# How to remove whitspaces in mysql column

Tags: php, mysql, replace, preg-replace, trim

I have a column in a mysql table which has extra whitespaces on the end. Although i already tried to do REPLACE and TRIM within mysql and `$output = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $input);` nothing seems to remove the extra whitespace or whatever it is in the end of the string.

The column is a varchar(255) collation utf8_general_ci. It contains an alphanumeric string which represents a flight number e. g. LH2214. I have another column which also is the same collation and also varchar(255) with the same alphanumeric strings, which doesn't have the extra whitespace after it.

I only can see the whitespace on my webpage, which has charset utf-8. But what i can't see is, if it is a tabspace, whitespace, eol, eof or similar, so i don't know how to filter it out. Does anybody have any ideas how do i get rid of the extra whitespace in the end of the values in my column in mysql?

I already tried a lot of solutions posted to similar questions her on SO, but none worked.

I added an image to show my problem.

[image: extra whitspace visible in the upper line.]

The funny thing is, that in the source-code, there is no whitespace visible. So if I save the html, i will not see an whitespace nor an `&nbsp;` or similar.

Comment: If trim doesn't work then the characters are probably not actually whitespace characters but rather some other characters that are unable to be displayed. Can you post an example here of the raw string?

Comment: how do i post the raw string? If i go into phpmyadmin, no extra characters is shown after the string, even in edit mode.

Comment: If you inspect the elements (with chrome devtools for example), you might be able to see some extra characters there...

Comment: This also might be a css setting you forgot about. I see that the two lines from your screen shot have different colors...That leads me to believe that there are different CSS rules being enforced on them. Perhaps that is your issue...

Comment: you are likely searching at the wrong end. Check that you output valid HTML, if not, fix the HTML structure first.

Comment: @Lix: your were right, it was an css issue. So I have to investigate why my queries are not firing. How can i thank you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me (from your screenshot), that you have some additional CSS properties on the rows that have the "additional whitespace". Take a look at your css properties, perhaps you set a margin, padding, text-indent or some other property that would shift your text/content.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible reasons for the additional whitespace come to my mind.

1. Trailing white-space characters are inserted into the table column.

You can verify and fix this ( for existing data )
Using the following Query:

```
UPDATE <your_table> SET <your_column> = TRIM ( <your_column> );
```

If this worked you should have a confirmation 'n rows updated' with n > 0

1. If this returned 0 rows updated you most likely have the whitespace added in your ouput.

Check your output HTML and Stylesheets

Comment: thank you for the response, but Lix already gave me this solution.